# Type-specific proof of UIP for type with decidable equality using induction

Tags: coq

If a type T in Coq has decidable equality, then all proofs of (x = x) are equal to eq_refl for x : T. This is "uniqueness of identity proofs" (UIP). There's a standard proof of this for any T. However, for a specific T (e.g. nat) there is (often? always?) an alternative proof that seems more direct. I'm curious if it always works or if there is a counterexample where the general proof technique works and the specific one doesn't.

```
Require Import Nat.

(* Convert bool to Prop *)

Definition IsTrue b := match b with
| true => True
| false => False
end.

(* Proof irrelevance for IsTrue b *)

Theorem IsTrue_unique : forall b (H1 H2 : IsTrue b), H1 = H2.
destruct b; simpl; intros.
destruct H1, H2.
apply eq_refl.
destruct H1.
Defined.

(* A lower-level definition of decidable equality that separates its computation: we
   have a decision procedure for equality (for nat it's _ =? _) such that IsTrue (n =? n) and  
  (IsTrue (m =? n) -> m = n) for all m, n.
*)

Fixpoint nat_eq_refl (n : nat) : IsTrue (n =? n) := match n with
| O => I
| S n' => nat_eq_refl n'
end.

(*
(* Or with tactics *)
Theorem nat_eq_refl_tac : forall n, IsTrue (n =? n).
induction n; simpl.
apply I.
apply IHn.
Defined.
*)

Fixpoint nat_eq_fwd {m n : nat} : IsTrue (m =? n) -> m = n :=
match m, n with
| O, O => fun G => eq_refl
| S m', S n' => fun G => match @nat_eq_fwd m' n' G with
  | eq_refl => eq_refl
  end
| _, _ => fun G => match G with end
end.

(*
(* With tactics *)
Theorem nat_eq_fwd_tac : forall m n, IsTrue (m =? n) -> m = n.
induction m; destruct n; simpl; intros G.
apply eq_refl.
destruct G.
destruct G.
destruct (IHm _ G).
apply eq_refl.
*)

(* From this, we can infer decidable equality. *)

Definition nat_eq_rev {m n : nat} (q : m = n) : IsTrue (m =? n) :=
match q with eq_refl => nat_eq_refl m end.

Theorem nat_eq_dec : forall (m n : nat), {m = n} + {m <> n}.
intros.
assert (Hfwd := @nat_eq_fwd m n).
assert (Hrev := @nat_eq_rev m n).
destruct (m =? n); simpl in *.
left.
apply (Hfwd I).
right.
intros H.
apply (Hrev H).
Defined.

(* Conversely, given nat_eq_dec we can "forget" the type information and get a function
   nat -> nat -> bool with the expected properties. (Not shown) *)

(* From this, we can prove UIP for nat, a la Hedberg. *)

Definition nu {m n : nat} (q : m = n) := nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_rev q).

Definition nu' {m n : nat} (q : m = n) := eq_trans (eq_sym (nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_refl m))) q.

Theorem nu_inv : forall {m n : nat} (q : m = n), nu' (nu q) = q.
unfold nu', nu.
destruct q; simpl.
destruct (nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_refl m)); simpl.
apply eq_refl.
Defined.

Theorem UIP : forall {m : nat} (q : m = m), q = eq_refl.
intros.
replace q with (nu' (nu q)).
replace eq_refl with (nu' (nu (eq_refl m))).
unfold nu', nu.
replace (nat_eq_rev q) with (nat_eq_rev (eq_refl m)).
apply eq_refl.
apply IsTrue_unique.
apply nu_inv.
apply nu_inv.
Defined.

(* And then trivially show that nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_refl m) = eq_refl. *)

Theorem nat_fwd_refl : forall {m : nat}, nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_refl m) = eq_refl.
intros.
apply UIP.
Defined.

(* But for nat we can also easily prove this directly via induction. *)

Theorem nat_fwd_refl' : forall {m : nat}, nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_refl m) = eq_refl.
induction m; simpl.
apply eq_refl.
rewrite IHm.
apply eq_refl.
Defined.

(* And get a (perhaps simpler?) proof of UIP for nat. *)

Theorem UIP' : forall {m : nat} (q : m = m), q = eq_refl.
intros.
replace q with (nat_eq_fwd (nat_eq_rev q)).
replace (nat_eq_rev q) with (nat_eq_refl m).
apply nat_fwd_refl'.
apply IsTrue_unique.
destruct q.
apply nat_fwd_refl'.
Defined.

(* Is the X_fwd_refl' proof via induction always possible in practice given
X_eq_refl and X_eq_fwd? Is there a space in a HoTT model where it isn't? *)
```

Comment: My highly shaky intuition is that if you have a nonrecursive set X of nats in a model of Coq then there could be a nonrecursive function X_eq that would satisfy X_eq_refl and X_eq_fwd but there could be no direct inductive proof of X_fwd_refl' since there'd be no induction principle. However, you couldn't define X in Coq. Anything you could define would allow the proof.

Comment: Why do you find this more direct than the general proof?

Comment: Primarily because we can use [nu u = u] instead of [nu' (nu u) = u]. Justifying the latter requires explaining some basic HoTT, I think, to justify eq_trans (eq_sym q) q = q.